# Docker container logs not found after dockerd restart

Tags: ubuntu, docker, logging, log-files, docker-swarm

I am running a Ubuntu 18.04 server with Docker (v20.10.12) containers running on it. I have about 5 containers running at a time and they consume about 1.5GB of memory on the regular, while my server has 8GB memory available. One of these 5 containers is leaking memory every 18-24h, it consumes all of the remaining memory and takes around 4-5GB in swap which makes my CPU and disk usage spike to 100%, which in turn causes the OOM killer to spawn and start culling processes, and one of them is dockerd.

After dockerd is killed I cannot find the logs of the said container that has the memory leak since the only ones I have in the filesystem are of the containers that spawned after dockerd restarted. So, I am completely in the dark in terms of what actually went on in that container without the logs, and this is exactly what I am trying to find.

I figured out which container leaked with `grep VmPeak /proc/{PID}/status` and got the PIDs with `docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' {CONTAINER_ID}`, which listed the ~11GB peak memory usage in one case. But, when I went to `/var/lib/docker/containers/` and checked all the folders, none had any logs before the actual OOM killer swipe and dockerd restart time. Also tried looking at `var/log/syslog` and it only showed me the OOM killer doing its thing and dockerd panicking with various network and firewall errors. If I am wrong and I should dive deep into the syslog, please let me know.

I don't necessarily need to get these logs, some help setting up some other solution which will preserve the logs elsewhere so that I can check them out the next time it crashes would also be very helpful, and could possibly solve the issue. But this is not related to the issue at hand, so I understand if it will be disregarded.